# how to fix issue "your code installation appears to be corrupt. please reinstall" in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

1. Here at first I installed the doki theme extension to change the background
2. Not long after, all my inline CSS styles ran into the problem of having to move them externally

[This is a photo of the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6wY6.jpg)

**I have followed the method**

1. install the Fix VSCode checksums extension
2. opened a prompt and typed "fix checksums:Apply"
3. restart vscode then open it

**but it doesn't work at all**

Answer (score 0):

Click the cog wheel and mute the notification. The checksum is failing against the workbench.html file because you have custom scripts. I have thousands of lines of css styling my vscode and I muted this notification long time ago

[image]